# How to find out use of unnamed partition in windows?

Tags: windows, partitioning, grub

I'm using windows 10 and Computer Management (Not an english computer, so not sure of .exe name). And i'm trying to extend my main partition.
I just deleted an old Linux partition, and in the end I've got 4 partitions on my ssd :

- System (350 Mo, NTFS) healthy(System, active, main partition)
- Windows (C:) 115,62 Go, NTFS healthy (Start, empty on incident, main partition)
- "" 500 Mo, healthy, (Main partition)
- "" 122,03 Go, Free space

(Subsidiary question : is there a way to use these windows util in english without changing the computer's language ?)

now I kind of suspect it might be a grub partition (which I don't have use of anymore, but my computer still boots on grub). And I would like to make my Windows partition to make use of those 122,53 unused Go.

How can I check what is on the third partition, to make sure I can delete it ?

Comment: You mean the 122,03 partition? That's the 4th partition, not the 3rd.

Comment: indeed, but this one is already free space, therefore, i don't need to know what is on this one !